# Command to search particular directories and delete a specific file within it

Tags: linux, shell, cpanel, whm

I'm extremely beginner at using SSH to accomplish tasks on my linux web server, but I'm trying to search for a particular file name (ex. abc.php) inside of just the public_html folder for each user account and delete abc.php.

So, right now, the structure looks like this:
/home/user1/public_html/
/home/user2/public_html/
/home/user3/public_html/

I only want to search within the public_html folders of each and then delete abc.php if it exists.

I've been using the 'find' command:
`find /home -name 'abc.php' -type`

... in combination with this modified one to find and delete files:
`find . -name "abc.php" | xargs rm`

...but I'd like to know how to search within a specific folder structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `path pattern` works:

```
find /home -path '**/public_html/*.php' -delete
```

by the way, you can use `ssh -t yourserver yourcommand`, this will close ssh connection automatically after execute the command in your server.

```
ssh -t yourserver find /home -path '**/public_html/*.php' -delete
```

Comment: This worked great, thanks!

How would you adjust to delete a directory (and contents) within "public_html"?